# Please specify value for '' explicitly

Tags: api, kotlin, annotations, java-17

Here I am again, struggling with kotlin.

Background: I am trying at the moment to upgrade an existing API to Java 17 and Kotlin 1.6.10.

But after building the project now, I got following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Usage of default value argument for this annotation is not yet possible.
Please specify value for 'DelimitedEnumSet.delimiter' explicitly
```

I am pretty sure the error must be somewhere here:

```
@JsonQualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
internal annotation class DelimitedEnumSet(val delimiter: String = " ")
```

The Stacktrace is not really helpful, so I am not 100% sure

Comment: Have you tried to specify value for 'DelimitedEnumSet.delimiter' explicitly? @DelimitedEnumSet(delimiter = " ") ...

Comment: Yes I did.... but I forgot the test classes D:
Thanks for bringing this idea back up, so that I needed to use my brain :'D

Just kidding, but really thank you!